# Plotly.graph_objects choropleth map - how to register an on click event?

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization

I am trying to visualize this dataset: https://www.kaggle.com/sdorius/globses. I am using plotly.graph_objects with Python. My goal is to have a choropleth map of the whole world which shows the SES percentile for each country for each decade from 1880 to 2010. Additionaly, I would like an extra barchart to be displayed when I click on a country, showing the GDPPP or SES percentile across the decades for the respective country.

I already have the choropleth map with a slider to choose the decade, but I am stuck at the barchart. The code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go

df = pd.read_csv('globses.csv', encoding='iso-8859-1')

min_year = 1880
data_all_years = []

for year in sorted(df.year.unique()):
    df_single_year = df[df['year'] == year]

    data_for_year = dict(
        type='choropleth',
        locations=df.country.unique(),
        z=df_single_year['SES'],
        locationmode='country names',
        marker=dict(
            line=dict(
                color='rgb(0,0,0)',
                width=1.5
            )
        ),
        colorbar=dict(
            title='SES'
        )
    )
    data_all_years.append(data_for_year)

steps = []
for i in range(len(data_all_years)):
    step = dict(method='restyle',
                args=['visible', [False] * len(data_all_years)],
                label='Year {}'.format(i * 10 + min_year))
    step['args'][1][i] = True
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [dict(
    active=0,
    pad={'t': 1},
    steps=steps
)]

layout = dict(
    title='Socioeconomic status percentile',
    sliders=sliders
)

def show_barchart(trace, points, state):
    # todo: show a barchart for clicked country


fig = go.Figure(data=data_all_years, layout=layout)
fig.data[0].on_click(show_barchart)
fig.show()
```

The issue is that wherever I click, the show_barchart function doesn't even get called. Is there any way to do it with Plotly in Python or should I just use some other library?

Thanks for any answers.